# JavaScript timeZone is not working while using IE, but works fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I wrote below code snippet to get time in a specified timeZone and format. This code works well in chrome but while using IE, it's showing below error message:
**Option value 'AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES' for 'timeZone' is outside of valid range. Expected: ['UTC']**

I need to use the timeZone with "America/Los_Angeles". I appreciate any help here.

```
function getPSTTime() {
    var usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"});
    usaTime = new Date(usaTime);
    var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    var ampm = usaTime.getHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    var date = usaTime .getDate()+'-'+ months[usaTime.getMonth()] +'-'+usaTime .getFullYear();
    var time = usaTime .getHours() + ":" + usaTime .getMinutes() + ":" + usaTime .getSeconds() + " " + ampm;
    var dateTime = date+' '+time;
    return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

IE11 has limited support of date formatting when using the timezone option. basically, the only valid option is UTC.

I suggest you can try to refer to an example below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/date-time-format-timezone@latest/build/browserified/date-time-format-timezone-complete-min.js"></script>

<script>
function updateTimes() {
   var dt = new Date();
  var els = document.querySelectorAll("[data-tz]");
  for (var l = 0; l < els.length; l ++) {
    var d = els[l];
    d.innerText = dt.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: d.dataset.tz});
  }
}

updateTimes();
setInterval(updateTimes, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span data-tz="America/Los_Angeles"></span>
  - America/Los_Angeles
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

Reference:

[IE 11 throwing “'timeZone' is outside of valid range” when setting timezone to “Europe/London”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364061/ie-11-throwing-timezone-is-outside-of-valid-range-when-setting-timezone-to)

**Edit:**

Below is the code example that uses only JS code:

```js
function updateTimes() {
   var dt = new Date();
   var str = dt.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"});
   console.log(str);
  }


updateTimes();
setInterval(updateTimes, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/date-time-format-timezone@latest/build/browserified/date-time-format-timezone-complete-min.js"></script>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input here. I just want to know that can we write this code as a javascript method instead of integrating in html. Also, can we get the time in this format: 15-May-2020 6:8:35 AM

Comment: Yes, you can write the code as a method. In the above example, you can see that I had declared the function. You can try to modify the code as per your own requirements.

Comment: Actually, I want to use data-tz="America/Los_Angeles" inside the javascript method itself so that I don't need to depend on html code. Can we have this inside JS? Please correct me if am wrong or missing something here.

Comment: You need to write like this in JS code. dt.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"});

Comment: we can't use dt.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}) as this will throw error in IE. My query is that how we can assign value to data-tz="America/Los_Angeles" in the below code: – var els = document.querySelectorAll("[data-tz]") without touching html code.

Comment: Please see the Edit section in my above answer. I have provided the example that uses only JS code and it is not dependent on the HTML. Let me know if you have any further questions. Thanks for your understanding.